# Adding days to dates using while loop

Tags: java

I am writing a program that adds days to the current date and already given dates. I am struggling to make my code add days correctly. I *think* I am doing the while loop for days correctly, but I also need to do a while loop for the months. How would I write my while loop for the months? The way that I see it is that I would need to continually add a month and subtract the appropriate number of days until I have less than 30 (or 31, or 29) days left and can’t simply add a month. Is that right? Is my code so far correct?

This is my code so far:

```
   class Dates {

    public String[] MONTH_NAMES = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    public List<Integer> ODD_MONTHS = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12);
    public int year;
    public int month;
    public int day;

    public Dates(int y, int m, int d) {
        day = d;
        month = m;
        year = y;
    }

    public void addDays(int days) {
        while (days > 365) {
            {
                if (isLeapYear()) {
                    days -= 1;
                }
                days -= 365;
                year += 1;
                if (isLeapYear() && month == 2 && day > 28 ) {
                    day -= 29;
                    month++;
                } else if (ODD_MONTHS.contains(month) && day > 30) {
                    day -= 31;
                    month++;
                } else if (day > 29) {
                    day -= 30;
                    month++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void subtractDays(int days) {
        year -= days / 365;
        days %= 365;
        month -= days / 30;
        days %= 30;
        day -= days;
        if (isLeapYear() && month == 2 && day > 28) {
            day += 28;
            month--;
        } else if (ODD_MONTHS.contains(month) && day > 31) {
            day += 31;
            month--;
        } else if (day > 30) {
            day += 30;
            month--;
        }
    }

    public boolean isLeapYear() {
        if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)  ){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getMonthName() {
        return MONTH_NAMES[month];
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public int getDayOfMonth() {
        return day;
    }

    public void printShortDate() {
        System.out.println(String.format("%d/%d/%d", month, day, year));
    }

    public void printLongDate() {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %d, %d", getMonthName(), day, year));
    }
}


class GregorianDate extends Dates {

    public GregorianDate() {
        super(1970, 1, 1);
        long milliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis() + java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
        int days = (int) milliSeconds / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        addDays(days);
    }

    public GregorianDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        super(year, month, day);
    }
}

class JulianDate extends Dates {

    public JulianDate() {
        super(1, 1, 1);
        addDays(719164);
        long milliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis() + java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
        int days = (int) milliSeconds / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        addDays(days);
    }

    public JulianDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        super(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not able/willing to use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)?

Comment: Date arithmetic is complicated! Did you know that every 100 years isn't a leap year? (e.g.: 2100, 1900). Except every 400 years (e.g.: 1600, 2000)? If possible consider using [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), or a third party library like [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/). They all give you the ability to *add 6 days* (or other chunks of time) and handle the *which month and day is it* part on their own.

Comment: won't your logic fail if 366 days is given to method(leap year is true)? will result in days = 0 !!

Comment: You should not reinventing the wheel in your program. The designers for java.time have gone through more consideration than you would think to bring out the date library. If this is your homework or exercise, that would be another story.

Comment: I cannot use java.time or Calendar. It has to be like that.

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534528/how-to-add-n-days-to-a-date-in-java-without-importing-date-calendar-from-java-ap ?

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment, do what the library methods do.  Convert the date to the number of days since January 1, 1970 (or some other date), add or subtract the days, and convert the number of days back to a date.

Comment: I think you need the change your code as @OleV.V. suggested. If you're adding 800 days, you want to first add two years. Then add months and days. Right now, you're adding just one year and directly going to your logic for months. I'd also suggest that you don't do your entire program in one go. Do a little, then make sure it works, then do a little more, then make sure that works. Else you'll end up with a bigger debugging problem if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use java 8 time. If not possible use Joda Time.

Both have the ability to add days to date, example:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
dateTime = dateTime.plusDays(1);
```

You shouldn't write it from the ground. Just use one of above.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think after looking at your code alone:

- Each of the `if` statements needs to go outside your `while` loop since there may be more months than years — up to 0 years 11 months. So you need to count the years in one loop and the months in another one after the first one.
- Those three `if` statements in turn need to be turned into one `while` loop to execute up to 11 times over up to 11 months of different lengths. So join the three `if` conditions using `||` (or) for the while loop and put the `if`- `else` chain inside that `while` loop.

**Edit:** After trying you code for one example, I think I have spotted the following bugs too:

1. In this line

   ```
   public String[] MONTH_NAMES = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
   ```

   I think that your months are 1-based (January is 1,  December is 12), and if so, you are getting your month names shifted because arrays in Java are 0-based: you have January at index 0, December at index 11 and an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` waiting for you when you need to print a date in the 12th month of a year.
2. Not a bug, only now we’re at it.

   ```
       while (days > 365) {
           {
   ```

   You don’t need to open *two* curly braces here, one would be fine and probably a bit easier to read.
3. You are confusing the variables `day` and `days` here:

   ```
               if (isLeapYear() && month == 2 && day > 28 ) {
                   day -= 29;
                   month++;
               } else if (ODD_MONTHS.contains(month) && day > 30) {
                   day -= 31;
                   month++;
               } else if (day > 29) {
                   day -= 30;
                   month++;
               }
   ```

   Think again about which one you need where.
4. You are never adding anything to `day` in your `addDays` method, only subtracting. This can’t be right.

Cases for you to think about:

1. If the date is `new Dates(2020, 2, 26)` (Feb 26, 2020) and you add 1 day, what should the `addDays` method do internally get to Feb 27?
2. If the date is `new Dates(2020, 2, 29)`, the last day of the month, the expected result from adding 1 day is March 1. How should `addDays` accomplish that?

As others have said, if there’s anyway that it is allowed, use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) rather than programming your own algorithm.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my question and added more code. It is not the whole code but I believe is the most important part. I would really appreciate if you could please take a look at it and tell me what could be improved as right now it is not really printing the correct addition and subtraction of dates. Thank you so much!